# Error while trying to build apk of TensorFlow Android Camera Demo

Tags: android, android-ndk, tensorflow

I'm following this [instruction](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android/) for TensorFlow Android Camera Demo, I changed path for NDK and SDK in WORKSPACE and now when I'm trying to build APK, using command

```
$ bazel build //tensorflow/examples/android:tensorflow_demo
```

I got such errors:

[image]

What I'm doing wrong? How to fix it?

If I'm trying to build APK in Android Studio I get such Errors:

```
Error:/private/var/tmp/_bazel_Iryna/c541cf0f6f349cf0d7c8d3692096116a/external/protobuf/BUILD:73:1: C++ compilation of rule '@protobuf//:protobuf_lite' failed: sandbox-exec failed: error executing command /usr/bin/sandbox-exec -f /private/var/tmp/_bazel_Iryna/c541cf0f6f349cf0d7c8d3692096116a/bazel-sandbox/a0350092-17a0-44fc-a63c-6321732c52f4-2/sandbox.sb /bin/false -MD -MF ... (remaining 27 argument(s) skipped).

Error:Execution failed for task ':buildNative'.
> Process 'command '/usr/local/bin/bazel'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Comment: This looks like an build/installation issue. Please file an issue at our [github](https://www.github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues) page. Try using both `--genrule_strategy=standalone` and `--spawn_strategy=standalone`.

Comment: @drpng How to use --genrule_strategy=standalone and --spawn_strategy=standalone ? If I print it in Terminal I got "command not found"

Comment: I mean `bazel build --genrule_strategy=standalone --spawn_strategy=standalone //tensorflow/examples/android:tensorflow_demo`

Comment: @drpng The same errors

Comment: OK, try filing an issue on our [github](https://www.github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues) page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exact Error was caused by the fact, that I didn't uncomment path to `NDK` and `SDK` in `WORKSPACE`. For more details read [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5534).